# Division returns within fixed percentage in a financial game.

Tags: normal-distribution, game-theory, finance, average

There is a game in which there are two types of member one who hold membership(X) and another who does not hold membership(Y). Membership is a stake out of total stakes which is S

I am trying to calculate the returns of the both member within the fixed percentage of returns lets say R = 10% on the total investment.

N as number of Investor.

Every member and non-member invest money(M) using S like

1. Calculating Stake ownership percentage P using S/Total Stake
2. Returning normal distribution T using for everyone R/N .
3. Then adding (P + T)* X + (P + T)*Y = R

But as my values in P changes it goes beyond R.

Any direction ?

You can see my edits I have come so far on my own before down voting.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank I tried . But I am stuck on the function part.

Comment: I am able to do something where I can get the Return / Total Number of Investor which will give the net return for the investor then adding the percentage of the ownership from StakesOwned/TotalStakes

Comment: This above equation is not compatible where value or token ownership changes the  , hence return value changes also .